# Kali Linux 2016 Rolling Inverted Mouse Scrolling

Tags: xorg, kali-linux, mouse, scrolling

My mouse scrolling is inverted I have taken a look at this post:

https://jamesmcdonald.com/2011/07/invert-mouse-scroll-wheel-in-debian/

But my config is like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "evdev pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection
```

With the `Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8"`

I have also enabled "natural scrolling" but no luck

Anyone has come accross the same issue and solved it¿? Thank you in advance

Comment: Try putting the above into `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-vmmouse.conf` instead of `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Still inverted :S

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get natural scrolling by [following a guide I found](https://andym3.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/the-one-line-method-of-getting-natural-scrolling-in-linux/). Here is the command I ran.

```
echo "pointer = 1 2 3 5 4 7 6 8 9 10 11 12" > ~/.Xmodmap && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```